# CLOB is null but it fails null check

Tags: plsql, null, clob

I have a clob variable which I'm checking for nullity. But it doesn't pass the null check.

```
  temp_appid_holder := NULL;

  if(temp_appid_holder = NULL) then
      dbms_output.put_line('temp is null');
  else 
      dbms_output.put_line('temp is not null');
  end if
```

The above control structure only prints 'temp is not null'.

I've tried printing the value of 'temp_appid_holder' but it prints nothing which means it's null.

Comment: `NULL` is not equal to ***anything***, including another `NULL`.

Comment: That's it. Can you post an answer and I'll accept it @PM77-1

Comment: Nah. It has been answered over and over.